# Integers are sometimes off by positive or negative 256 when reading bytes from a binary file in C++

Tags: c++

I have a data set that's in binary, and I'm trying to extract 16-bit integers by reading in 2 bytes at a time. I'm trying to copy an implementation that I already have in JavaScript, which means that I have the correct output to test against. For some odd reason, 8 out of 120 integers read in are off by exactly 256 in either direction. At first I thought the I was misreading a single bit, but after looking at the numbers in binary, some are off by more than one bit. For example, one of the integers read in was 1297 (11000010001), when it should have been 1553 (10100010001), where the 2nd and 3rd most significant bit differ. Does anyone see where I'm going wrong? I can post the correct JavaScript code if that helps.

```
ifstream inputFile (inp, ios::binary);
int test = 0;
int fileHeaderOffset = 80+648+2700;
int x = 840;
int y = 359;
int columnBytes = 2414;
int width = 120;
int height = 121;

int16_t buff[height * 2];
int offset = fileHeaderOffset + (x * columnBytes) + (y * 2) + 8;
inputFile.seekg(offset+1);
for(int j = 0; j < height * 2; j++){
   inputFile.read((char*)&buff[test], 2);
   test++;
}
```

Comment: More useful than the javascript source would be a [mcve] that includes a small sample file that triggers the error This is one exceedingly rare time where I would link to the input file rather than embedding it into the post. Binary data and HTML don't mix well.

Comment: Note that the "2nd and 3rd most significant bits" of that value are the 8th and 9th bits, i.e., the low bits of the upper byte. Those low bits are the only place where the value can be off by 256 from what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what my issue was. I was reading a byte too far, and also failing to byte swap. The extra byte of seek causes it to grab the low byte of the correct integer, and the high byte of the integer after it. Since the integers doesn't change much between points, the high bytes of adjacent points are usually identical, so it usually works, but when the integer passes a multiple of 256, the high byte changes, and that byte is off by 1, which means the number is off by 256.